# I am finally updating our Google Ads API calls. Why is the code that uses www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga still working for SOME accts

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-4

We pull Google Ad metrics for our clients, such as cost and conversions.  I am finally getting around to updating the code to the new api.

I THOUGHT that the analytics/v3 api was to be shut down in July, but I see that we are still getting data for SOME of our clients when using the old API.  Is anyone else seeing this?  I am wondering if I should work on getting analytics/v3 api to work for all clients, or re-code to use the new Data api v1.

Thoughts/ideas/suggestions appreciated!

Comment: My understanding is a) that UA for GA 360 accounts is still live and supported, if that is relevant, but that other UA data flow may be withdrawn at any time from July 1st 2023 onwards on an account by account basis. I have been trying to find out if there will be any warning, but needless to say Google seems incapable of answering questions even if you can find a non-moribund channel on which to ask them. I would suggest you migrate everything to GA4 compatibility asap, effort put in to UA at this point feels to me like time wasted.